# how to update dataframe columns based on condition using pipe() and apply()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm relatively new to pandas library and I'm stuck at two functions pipe() and apply(). I'm trying to find the difference between two functions, but couldn't find any resource which explains in an easily understandable way.

Also, I have this function that I have created o use with pipe() and apply(), but whenever I want to add '2' to a column it works fine but as I replace it with conditional if else part it gives error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

```
    def lol(e1):
        if(e1 > 3):
           return "High"
        else:
           return "Low"


data = {'Name': ['Giggs', 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Jack', 'Jill', 'Scholes', 'Martial', 'Rashford', 'Pogba'],
                'Age': [23,21,24,21,20,10,23,45,22,35],
                'Rating': [4.23, 3.21, 2.10, 1.91, 4.32, 6.32, 4.19, 2.09, 1.09, 3.33]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5','A6','A7','A8','A9','A10'])

print(df[['Rating', 'Age']].pipe(lol))
print(df[['Rating', 'Age']].apply(lol,axis=1))
```

I'm unable to make any progress. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your use case, you don't need to use pipe. You should use apply.

```
df.Rating.apply(lol)

A1     High
A2     High
A3      Low
A4      Low
A5     High
A6     High
A7     High
A8      Low
A9      Low
A10    High
Name: Rating, dtype: object
```

Pipe is only used when you want to reference the whole DataFrame, for example:

```
df.pipe(lambda x: pd.concat([x,x]))
```

This will concat the DataFrame with itself.

If you pass multiple columns via apply, the passed value is a series. You can access the element via its index.

For example, if you want to do this:

```
df[['Rating', 'Age']].apply(lol,axis=1)
```

You need to change your function to:

```
def lol(e1):
    if(e1.Rating > 3):
       return "High"
    else:
       return "Low"
```

Comment: I'm able to make changes with apply() according to condition if I provide only one column name but if I provide multiple columns like I have provided above in my code, that is where the issue begins as it does not change both the columns.

Comment: What do you try to do with 2 columns? Which column do you want to compare with 3 in your function?

Comment: I was trying to use apply function and see how it works if I want to use conditional statement on my dataframe and then update it on the basis of condition. I’m trying to learn pandas and want to know how dataframes function works.

Comment: Have updated the answer with examples to show how you can pass multiple columns in apply.

Comment: So, in that case i have to mention each column separately? Like e1. Rating and e1.Age to make amendment to both the columns in single function? Thanks for answeringmy questions patiently, appreciate it.